# Is there a need to use hasOwnProperty with Object.keys?

Tags: javascript, properties, hasownproperty

if I iterate over an object, I need to check whether it is not a prototype object I loop over. (with hasOwnProperty)

If I collect the keys with Object.keys, I always just get the "real keys" back. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `Object.keys()` gives you the keys of the properties directly on the object. So you *could* use that.

Keep in mind that `Object.keys()` may not be supported in every one of your target browsers if you're doing front-end development.

Comment: Thanks you! Tha means it's always better to do this: for( var i in Object.keys(obj)) than doing this: for(var i in obj) because the prototype attributes are filtered out?

Comment: @Christian I'd use a normal `for` loop, as the result is an Array. You could still be bitten by enumerable properties from extending the Object or Array prototype otherwise.